# При попытке отправить электронное сообщение вылетает исключение javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: javamail

Доброго времени суток!
У меня возникла проблема при работе с JavaMail API, при попытке отправить сообщение вылетает исключение

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no
>   password specified

Вот код:

```
package sendmail;
```

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created by caesar-84 on 9/28/16.
 */
public class SslGmailSender
{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Properties props;

```
public SslGmailSender(String username, String password)
{
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;

    props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
}

public void send(String subject, String text, String from, String to)
{
    Session thisSession = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator()
    {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentification()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(SslGmailSender.this.username, SslGmailSender.this.password);
        }
    });
    try
    {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(thisSession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);

        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Yor e-mail has been sent.");
    }
    catch (MessagingException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

И main()

```
package sendmail;
```

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Created by caesar-84 on 9/28/16.
 */
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        String subject = "";
        String text = "";
        String to = "";
        try(BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
        {
            System.out.print("Your e-mail: ");
            username = console.readLine();
            System.out.print("Password: ");
            password = console.readLine();
            System.out.print("Recipient: ");
            to = console.readLine();
            System.out.print("Message subject: ");
            subject = console.readLine();
            System.out.println("Text to send (type \"-END\" to finish):");
            String typedText = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (!typedText.contains("-END"))
            {
                typedText = console.readLine();
                sb.append(typedText).append("\n");
            }
            sb.delete(sb.length() - 4, sb.length());
            text = sb.toString();

```
    }
    catch (IOException ex){ex.getStackTrace();}

    String from = username;
    SslGmailSender thisSender = new SslGmailSender(username, password);
    thisSender.send(subject, text, from, to);
}
```

}

[image: Вывод:]

Answer (score 0):

Решено следующим образом:

```
package sendmail;
```

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created by caesar-84 on 9/28/16.
 */
public class SslSender
{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Properties props;
    private String smtpMailProvider;
    final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

```
public SslSender(String username, String password)
{
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    if (username.substring(username.indexOf("@") + 1, username.length()).equals("hotmail.com"))
    this.smtpMailProvider = "smtp.live.com";
    else this.smtpMailProvider = "smtp." + username.substring(username.indexOf("@") + 1, username.length());

    props = System.getProperties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpMailProvider);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", smtpMailProvider);


}

public void send(String subject, String text, String from, String to)
{
    Session thisSession = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator()
    {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(SslSender.this.username, SslSender.this.password);
        }
    });
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(thisSession);

    try
    {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);

        Transport transport = thisSession.getTransport();
        transport.connect(smtpMailProvider, username, password);
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Your e-mail has been sent.");
    }
    catch (MessagingException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Uuups... something went wrong...");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(2);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: PS. Не работает для hotmail